# I can not install the evolution in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, evolution

I can not install the evolution in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

i tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fta/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

output:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
Some packages could not be installed. Perhaps you are asking the impossible,
or using the unstable distribution that some required
packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help you:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
evolution: Depends: libevolution (= 3.13.7-fta1.2 ~ trusty) but it will not be installed
          Depends: bogofilter but it can not be installed
          Depends: spamassassin but it can not be installed
          Depends: highlight but it can not be installed
          Depends: gnome-icon-theme-full (> = 2.30.2.1) but it can not be installed
          Recommends: evolution-plugins but it will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have delayed (held) broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing packages separately (that were the unmet dependencies)? Have you tried installing through *Software Center*?

Comment: try installing it from software center, its very easy to install from there

Answer (score 1):

solved in [answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+question/258829](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+question/258829) after inclusion of all previously switched off, jackdaws in repositories in Synaptic tab "software" and remove some of the old in the "other software" .and .....WAU.....evolution (his test release 3.12) has been successfully installed !